# Existe algun metodo en php que se parezca al indexof, push y reduce

Tags: php, javascript

Buenas era para saber si en php existe algo parecido al indexof, push y reduce de javascipt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` ~ [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php)

```
$array = array(0 => 'azul', 1 => 'rojo', 2 => 'verde', 3 => 'rojo');

$clave = array_search('verde', $array); // $clave = 2;
$clave = array_search('rojo', $array);  // $clave = 1;
```

`push` ~ [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)

```
$pila = array("naranja", "plátano");
array_push($pila, "manzana", "arándano");
print_r($pila);

// Resultado:
Array
(
    [0] => naranja
    [1] => plátano
    [2] => manzana
    [3] => arándano
)
```

`reduce` ~ [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-reduce.php)

```
function suma($carry, $item)
{
    $carry += $item;
    return $carry;
}

function producto($carry, $item)
{
    $carry *= $item;
    return $carry;
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$x = array();

var_dump(array_reduce($a, "suma")); // int(15)
var_dump(array_reduce($a, "producto", 10)); // int(1200), ya que: 10*1*2*3*4*5
var_dump(array_reduce($x, "suma", "No hay datos a reducir")); // string(22) "No hay datos a reducir"
```